# Focus Gained and Focus Lost Java

Tags: java

I have some text field on my form. And I like focusGained and focusLost event. Doing this with 2 or 3 text field is easy. But, after 18 text field, well, it's kinda confusing.
Is there any way to shorten the focusGained and focusLost event?
Example:

```
txtSomeTextFocusGained(java.awt.event FocusEvent evt){
    if(txtSomeText.getText().equals("Text here!"){
        txtSomeText.setText("");
    }
}

txtSomeTextFocusLost(java.awt.event FocusEvent evt){
    if(txtSomeText.getText().equals(""){
        txtSomeText.setText("Text here!");
    }
}
```

That's one text field, I've problem handling with about 18 text field. Any way to simplify that?
Thanks.

Comment: edit your question to explain it better

Comment: How? I'm new at asking. Thanks.

Comment: IF you're doing the same thing for all 18 text fields (event wise) you can just use the same event handler for each text field

Comment: Use Eclipse or Netbeans. Keyboard shrtcuts can ease the burden. Eclipse also is great at copy-pasting stuff like this

Comment: @bentinata: There is an edit link below the questions tags on the left side.

Comment: @Adel if your solution is "copy and paste 17 times," well, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods are simple enough, so I can't think of a way to simplify them any further. What you **can** do, though, is prevent code repetition by declaring **one** FocusListener instance and then add it using `addFocusListener(...)` to **all** text-fields.

It would look something like this:

```
// Instantiate a FocusListener ONCE
java.awt.event.FocusListener myFocusListener = new java.awt.event.FocusListener() {
    public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent focusEvent) {
        try {
            JTextField src = (JTextField)focusEvent.getSource();
            if (src.getText().equals("Text here!") {
                src.setText("");
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException ignored) {
            /* I only listen to JTextFields */
        }
    }

    public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent focusEvent) {
        try {
            JTextField src = (JTextField)focusEvent.getSource();
            if (src.getText().equals("") {
                src.setText("Text here!");
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException ignored) {
            /* I only listen to JTextFields */
        }
    }
};
```

(You could omit the `try-catch` blocks if you were **absolutely** sure that the source of the event would always be a JTextField, but it is always a bad practice to rely on such assumptions.)

Then, for every JTextField you only need to add the **same** FocusListener:

```
...
someTextField.addFocusListener(myFocusListener);
...
```

(It's only half a line - difficult to get any shorter than that.)

---

Another alternative would be to subclass JTextField, adding a FocusListener in the constructor, but I don't see any advantage over the first solution (unless you want a more flexible/powerful solution, e.g. different text for each JTextField etc).

Comment: Great thanks. Even I'm sure **absolutely** that that the source always jTextField, I'll never omit the try-catch, it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to set some text in field which gets focused you could write separated event handler class which implements `FocusListener` and then override `focusGained` and `focusLost` methods. Something like this:

```
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CustomFocusListener implements FocusListener {
    JTextField txt;
    String textWhenFocusGained;
    String textWhenFocusLost;

    public CustomFocusListener(JTextField txt, String textWhenFocusGained,
            String textWhenFocusLost) {
        this.txt = txt;
        this.textWhenFocusGained = textWhenFocusGained;
        this.textWhenFocusLost = textWhenFocusLost;
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
        txt.setText(textWhenFocusGained);
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
        txt.setText(textWhenFocusLost);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
if(txtSomeText.getText().equals("Text here!")){
    txtSomeText.setText("");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/////////////// It's problem of lower and supper case you should make ur text in lower case in code. and for desing of jtextfield it's ok
    txtIdDeVoyageur = new JTextField();
    txtIdDeVoyageur.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
             if(txtIdDeVoyageur.getText().trim().toLowerCase().equals("id de voyageur")){
                 txtIdDeVoyageur.setText("");
                 txtIdDeVoyageur.setForeground(Color.black);
                }

        }
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            if (txtIdDeVoyageur.getText().trim().equals("") || 
                    txtIdDeVoyageur.getText().trim().toLowerCase().equals("id de voyageur"))
                {

                txtIdDeVoyageur.setText("id de voyageur");
                txtIdDeVoyageur.setForeground(new Color (153,153,153));

                }
        }
    });
```