# How to Display Message When i left JTextField in java

Tags: java

Actually i'm writing code. I want to display **message dialogue** (without pressing any button) **when I left my `JTextField`**  but don't know how to do this. Please Help. Im using NetBeans.

Comment: Can you share your code. code that you tried so far.

Comment: i have not written code yet it's logic that i want to implement in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Focus Listener API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) to achieve that.

On `focusLost` event, you can show your dialog box.

Example from the documentation:

```
public void focusLost( FocusEvent e )
{
    displayMessage( "Focus lost", e );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FocusListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) class [focusLost()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947532/focus-gained-and-focus-lost-java) method.

Simple Example:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ExampleClass {
    JFrame MainFrame;
    JTextField textField1;
    JTextField textField2;

    public ExampleClass(){
        MainFrame = new JFrame("Example");
        MainFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        textField1 = new JTextField(10);
        textFieldFocus();

        textField2 = new JTextField("Dummy text");

        MainFrame.add(textField1);
        MainFrame.add(textField2);
        MainFrame.pack();
        MainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void textFieldFocus() {                                     
        textField1.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done!");

            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {}
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ExampleClass();
    }
}
```